# How do add a route in Zend with a module name

Tags: zend-framework, url-rewriting, routes

I want to add a route in my Zend Framework application.
I want a route like this:

```
example.com/modulename/titleofthearticle-12
```

who redirect to:

```
example.com/modulename/article/index/id/12
```

I made this code, but I don't know how to add the module name in the route:

```
$router = $front_controller->getRouter();
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    'modulename/[a-z\-]*-([0-9]*)',
    array('controller' => 'article', 'action' => 'index'),
    array(1 => 'id')
);
$router->addRoute('article', $route);
```

How to add this module name in the route ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$router = $front_controller->getRouter();

$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    'modulename/[a-z\-]*-([0-9]*)',
    array(
        'module'     => 'modulename',
        'controller' => 'article',
        'action'     => 'index'),
    array(
        1 => 'id'
    )
);

$router->addRoute('article', $route);
```